# How to track the moment when all app animation is over in Angular?

Tags: angular, algorithm, animation, events, angular-animations

I'm learning Angular, and I've got a task to create Three in a row game (looks like on the pic).

[image]

When all appeared triples are found, and animation of falling down balls is over, I need to check if new triples were formed.

So now I have two ways of getting the moment when animation of each ball is finished: through timeout and through increment. Both ones work with help of callbacks on (@animation.start) and (@animation.done) events of each ball.

***Now the question.***

I guess that my methods are not the best practices, and there is a way of tracking if **all the app animation is over**. I'm using Angular v.6.0.3.

I'm a novice in Angular, and any advises will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think making a callback on animation.end is a bad thing?

Comment: @Kepotx Callback on animation.end is a good thing. But in my case it does not elegant, and looks like some kind of a crutch. I make some action EVERY time when ball falls on (@animation.end). I suspect there is some event or some architectural solution for tracking if all the app animation is over.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the recent angular version (i.e. 6.x.x or up) you now have the ability to use call backs on your animations.

You can use the methods start and done on the trigger for your animation as specified below.

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
        (@flyInOut.start)="animationStarted($event)"
        (@flyInOut.done)="animationDone($event)"
        [@flyInOut]="'in'">
      {{hero.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

read more [HERE](https://angular.io/guide/animations#animation-callbacks)

Comment: I've read the docs, my question is not much about that. I'm looking for a way of tracking the moment when all the app animation is over, not an animation of a single component.